# Implementing a language in Haskell: dynamic typing for polymorphic functions?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, dsl, dynamic-typing

I’m writing a programming language using Haskell as the host language. (The parser, grammar, runtime, etc. for my language are all written in Haskell.)

Depending on what’s written in a program in my PL, in my language’s runtime, I want to apply Haskell functions of different types dynamically (their types are known at runtime) to Haskell values of different types, whose types are known at runtime. I want to apply these functions in a generic fashion, without having to case on every possible type. Basically I want this part of my language’s runtime to be dynamically-typed in Haskell. I’d also like to write a typechecker for my language.

Any suggestions for how I might do either of these things? Are there any examples of languages written in Haskell that do a similar thing, whose approaches I can learn from?

One complication: The Haskell functions and values need to be polymorphic over floats because I am using them with a Haskell autodiff library (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad), which requires that floats have type (Floating a => a).

I tried using the Haskell Data.Dynamic and Data.Typeable libraries to make functions and values dynamic so I could compare their types at runtime and apply the functions if the types match, but Data.Dynamic doesn’t seem to allow polymorphic functions to be cast to Dynamic. The documentation even says this. I googled “Haskell polymorphic functions dynamic” but I don’t see a way around this limitation.

I would rather not force all the Haskell functions to have the same input/output type, and I would rather not have to statically list all of their possible types in a sum type. Maybe I can solve the applying-function problem with some kind of generic Applyable typeclass? Or use Template Haskell? None of these options sounds super appealing.

Comment: You could wrap polymorphic functions under a newtype, and then use `Dynamic`. If you have many functions with distinct types, though, it can be tedious to invent all those newtypes.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this without knowing more about your problem domain, but here is one approach that might work:

1. Group your types and functions into modules: see if your application deals with `Foo` types and has a set of corresponding functions that manipulate them, and `Bar` types with a largely disjoint set of functions. A real-world example might be numerical functions and string functions. There are a few cross-overs, but mostly they are separate types with different functions. Try to write these functions so that all the `Foo` and `Bar` parameters are at the end, so prefer `f :: String -> Foo -> Foo` over `f :: Foo -> String -> Foo`
2. Create a union type `FooBar = data Dfoo Foo | Dbar Bar` and associated [prisms](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16/docs/Control-Lens.html) `_Foo` and `_Bar`.
3. Write a family of functions to lift the `Foo` and `Bar` functions into the `FooBar` type by using the prisms you defined in step 2.

For instance,

```
  elevate2 :: Prism' b a -> (a -> a -> a) -> b -> b -> Maybe b
  elevate2 prism f arg1 arg2 = f <$> arg1 ^? prism <*> arg2 ^? prism
```

Each of your operations is now dynamically typed; when applied to the right arguments you get `Just` your result, and with the wrong arguments you get `Nothing`. If you prefer you could return an `Either` instead of `Maybe` to get more information about what went wrong, but that would require a lot more machinery in your elevation functions.